# How to delete learned data?

Tags: python-3.x, cjk, chatterbot

After learning database - A, I want to delete learned things once and then learn database - B.
However, in the method I tried, I can not erase what I learned once.
I will learn both database - A and database - B.

What you want to hear
· How to delete learned data

---

I upload chatterbot to web using django.
Use python 3

I am a Japanese and I use a translation site, so it may be a bit confusing question.

Comment: You're right! This _is_ a confusing question.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad I'm sorry.
I will question briefly.
How to delete chatterbot learning data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all dialog data (statements, responses, and tags) from a chat bot's database, the `drop` method can be called on the storage adapter for the `ChatBot` instance.

Here is a brief example:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

chatbot = ChatBot('Example Bot')

chatbot.storage.drop()
```

In addition to the programmatic method of deletion, because you are using Django, you might also find the Django Admin convenient for deleting and modifying individual responses. More information on the Django admin can be found in their documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/